# JPA mapping - Retrieve attribute from a different table

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I have these two tables..

user

- id
- username (nullable=true)
- fullname

comment

- id
- user_id (fk)
- text

And I want to retrieve a comment with an attribute from user table, like this..

public class Comment {

private Long id;

private Long username;

…

}

Comment: Do you mapped your Entity?

Answer (score 3):

You can very well use the concept of [secondary table](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html)

This will allow you to achieve the above mentioned case. Like given below:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "comment")
   @SecondaryTable(name = "user", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id",  referencedColumnName="id"))
   public class Comment {
      @Id
      @Column(name="id")
      private Long commentId;

     @Column(table="user", name="username")
     private Long userName;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was my first guess but it creates a dependency between user and comment. I cannot persist a user without a comment or else  "integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; FK459C57292A87E35 table: USER". I think @SecundaryTable only applies for one-to-one scenarios and joins through both pks. Not many(comments)-to-one(user).